# Unable to archive version 2.0 of app that contains cocoapods

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, cocoapods

My version 1.0 of my IOS app has been uploaded to the App store. I wished to update it and submit a version 2.0 to the app store as I noticed some typos in the app.

The only thing I changed in the app was literally on line of a string that contained the typo and the version box from 1.0 to 2.0. When I went to archive the app to submit it on the app store the workspace would not archive. The error that was presented was:

> no such module'HCVimeoVideoExtractor'

`HCVimeoVideoExtractor` is a pod file that is used in the app and is present in version 1.0 of the app.
I cannot figure out why it archived version 1.0 but will not archive version 2.0.

I am in the `.workspace` file so so I'm not sure what the issue is.

Comment: Did you update the cocoa pods before archiving for v2.0?

Comment: Does this only happen when you try to archive? Or also when you build and run the app?

Comment: @VictorSanchez   Yes it works perfectly when i run the app however the issue only occurs when i try to archive it.

Comment: @BhargavR  Yes I've also tried uninstalling and updating coco pods and reinstalling